# Revoking Celery Tasks Gevent Pool

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery, gevent, task-queue

I have been trying to revoke some Celery tasks by using
`app.control.revoke(task_id)`

As I am currently using gevent pool, I do understand that you would not be able to revoke a task that is currently executing [as seen here](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/4019).

However, it seems like I can't revoke tasks that are queued as well (base on what I can see from rabbitmq, these tasks are unacked). Do correct me if I am wrong, these queued tasks have yet to be executed and it should have nothing to do with the execution pool. How revoke works is that workers will have a copy of that task_id that is supposed to be revoked, save it (persistent revoke), and when the task reaches the worker, the worker will skip it.

I am using docker to coordinate everything and have included `--statedb=/celery/celery.state` . This file exists in the directory of the docker worker container so that should be fine.